# Trustworthy traders with the martyrs and the prophets on the say of judgment

Tags: day-of-judgement

In the Hadith a truthful trustworthy trader will be amongst the martyrs and prophets on the day of judgment. So how are the traders being categorised as shaheed in this hadith and why ?

Comment: Can you please consider citing the hadith number or the book wherein the hadith is written? Thanks.

Comment: https://sunnah.com/mishkat:2796